# Unable to open JNLP client

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I was trying to open an JNLP client but it fails every time throwing an exception.

```
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system
Unsigned resource:URL/beans/molecule.jar
```

Yesterday it was working, but this morning it Java asked for an update and I did it. After that I am facing this problem.

Please suggest me what i can do to handle this.

Answer (score 6):

**A new page to resolve this issue has been posted on java.com
http://java.com/en/download/help/clearcache_upgrade.xml**

-Duke

Comment: Awesome. How did you find this?

Comment: Thanks Duke and everyone.
Awesome share.

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing your Java Cache.
Instructions:  http://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it looks like you have an unsigned jar.  You could try [signing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html) it and retrying.

Comment: Our customers are having the issue also, and the app is signed. It's intermittent. Not every user experiences the error, but the solution is to clear the Java cache.